# MySQL - multiple count, min, max query

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
SELECT
`name`, count(`cid`) AS count, Min(`price-3`) AS min, Max(`price-3`) AS max
FROM ed_prices
WHERE type="M"
GROUP BY cid, type
```

This query gives me what I want for type M. But I have 4 different types like M and a result for every one of them is necessary. While this query gives me a result like this:

```
name, count, min, max
```

I need a result like this:

```
name, countM, minM, maxM, countP, minP, maxP, countZ, minZ, maxZ ...
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not exactly what you're looking for but could you maybe work with this:

```
SELECT `name`
      , type                     -- you'll want to include the type for each line item 
                                 -- to be able to identify which type the values refer to
      , count(`cid`) AS count
      , Min(`price-3`) AS min
      , Max(`price-3`) AS max          
FROM ed_prices
WHERE type IN ("M","P","Z","Q")  -- where M, P, Z, Q are the different product types
GROUP BY cid, type
```

You could also try a self join on this to combine the results into one *line*, to get the results as you requested in the question but it is less scalable for anything more than a handful of products..

```
SELECT `name`
      , countM
      , minM
      , maxM
      , countZ
      , minZ
      , maxZ
      , countP
      , minP
      , maxP
      , countQ
      , minQ
      , maxQ
  FROM 
       (SELECT `name`
              , count(`cid`) AS countM
              , Min(`price-3`) AS minM
              , Max(`price-3`) AS maxM
          FROM ed_prices
         WHERE type = "M"
         GROUP BY cid) MType
  INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT `name`
              , count(`cid`) AS countP
              , Min(`price-3`) AS minP
              , Max(`price-3`) AS maxP
          FROM ed_prices
         WHERE type = "P"
         GROUP BY cid) PType ON MType.`name` = PType.`name`
  INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT `name`
              , count(`cid`) AS countZ
              , Min(`price-3`) AS minZ
              , Max(`price-3`) AS maxZ
          FROM ed_prices
         WHERE type = "Z"
         GROUP BY cid) ZType ON MType.`name` = ZType.`name`
  INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT `name`
              , count(`cid`) AS countQ
              , Min(`price-3`) AS minQ
              , Max(`price-3`) AS maxQ
          FROM ed_prices
         WHERE type = "Q"
         GROUP BY cid) QType ON MType.`name` = QType.`name`
```

Comment: It's not helping in my situation. I need to separate the results in different columns.

Comment: @gzg, how about the second version?

Comment: I think it's almost done but something is missing or wrong. It leads to an empty result set, I don't know why.

Comment: I believe this should work. I'm about to make it work. The empty set result is arised from my db.

Comment: It works. Thank you! One question though. It doesn't show me the result of that name, if that name does not have all of the MType, PType and QType etc. It has to show whether one of the types are missing. How can I do that?

Comment: Done with left join. Thank you again!